# How can I make LyX work with Beamer on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, lyx, beamer

What do I need to install and/or do to use LyX for Beamer documents on Windows 7?

I've installed LyX and MiKTeX, but when I try to create a new Beamer document, I get an error.

Answer (score 1):

LyX does not install the Beamer document class by default on Windows7. Use the MiKTeX package manager to install the necessary packages. Then, open LyX and hit Tools>Reconfigure. The Beamer document will work now.